# Javascript click event on button with child markup

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener, event-delegation

Trying to understand event delegation without the use of jQuery. I setup a event listener `click` on a container div. I want to limit the `click` to a `button` within the container. The problem is when the `button` contains markup, the target is the element within the `button` and not the `button` itself. I thought the event would bubble up the DOM and also trigger a `mouseEvent` on he `button` as well. This doesn't seem to be the case. Wondering why or what I'm missing? I've seen demos of this working, but can't seem to reproduce it.

http://jsbin.com/qubuma

```js
const clickHandler = e => {
  console.log(e);
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return
  console.log('Clicked the button!');
}

const container = document.querySelector('.js-container');
container.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<div class="container js-container">
  <!-- Plain Button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn js-button">Login</button>

  <!-- SVG Button -->
  <button type="button" class="iconBtn js-button">
        <span class="u-isVisuallyHidden">Close</span>
        <span class="iconBtn-icon">
          <svg class="iconBtn-icon-inner">
            <use xlink:href="#heart"></use>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Warning: I tried running the above code, it hung my browser when I clicked onthe container.

Comment: Hmm, I think the hang comes from Stack Snippet's console emulator when it tries to log the event. It eventually finishes.